# My firebase cloud function tells me: Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout', but why? What is wrong with my code :(

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

my english is not the best (so sorry) and i'm very new to firebase stuff.

Could someone tell me (just if u have some time left for me), why my cloud function in the log tells me: Function execution took 60004 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'. The function is doing fine, but i don't like the server log ^^

Maybe my code is also completely wrong programmed, but yeah, as i said "i'm new to this" and i try my best to get better :)

this is my full code of the function:

```
exports.winSumCountRound = functions.database.ref('/casebattle/{id}/currentCountRound').onUpdate(async (snapshot, context) => {
    let currentCountRound = snapshot.after.val();

    if (currentCountRound >= 1) {
        const pathId = context.params.id;
        const caseCount = (await admin.database().ref('/casebattle/'+pathId+'/caseCount').once('value')).val();
        const users = (await admin.database().ref('/casebattle/'+pathId+'/users').once('value')).val();
        const currentWinSum = (await admin.database().ref('/casebattle/'+pathId+'/winSum').once('value')).val();

        const getWinSumArray = await users.map(async (user, index) => {
            const wonItemUser = (await admin.database().ref('/casebattle/'+pathId+'/itemWins/'+index+'/'+(currentCountRound - 1)).once('value')).val();

            currentWinSum[index] = currentWinSum[index] + wonItemUser.price;

            if (typeof wonItemUser.sticker_1 !== 'undefined' && wonItemUser.sticker_1 !== false) {
                currentWinSum[index] = currentWinSum[index] + wonItemUser.sticker_1.price;
            }
            if (typeof wonItemUser.sticker_2 !== 'undefined' && wonItemUser.sticker_2 !== false) {
                currentWinSum[index] = currentWinSum[index] + wonItemUser.sticker_2.price;
            }
            if (typeof wonItemUser.sticker_3 !== 'undefined' && wonItemUser.sticker_3 !== false) {
                currentWinSum[index] = currentWinSum[index] + wonItemUser.sticker_3.price;
            }
            if (typeof wonItemUser.sticker_4 !== 'undefined' && wonItemUser.sticker_4 !== false) {
                currentWinSum[index] = currentWinSum[index] + wonItemUser.sticker_4.price;
            }
        });

        return Promise.all(getWinSumArray).then( async () => {
            await admin.database().ref('casebattle/' + pathId + '/winSum').set(currentWinSum);

            if(currentCountRound >= caseCount){
                return await new Promise(() => setTimeout(async () => {
                    await admin.database().ref('casebattle/' + pathId + '/winSumFinished').set(true);
                    await admin.database().ref('/casebattle/'+pathId+'/isRunning').set(false);

                    return await users.map(async (user) => {
                        await admin.database().ref('/playedbattles/'+user.userId+'/'+pathId+'/isRunning').set(false);
                        return await admin.database().ref('/playedbattles/'+user.userId+'/'+pathId+'/winSumFinished').set(true);
                    });
                }, 2000));
            } else {
                return await new Promise(async () => {
                    return await admin.database().ref('casebattle/' + pathId + '/currentCountRound').transaction(currentCountRound => currentCountRound + 1);
                });
            }
        });
    } else {
        return null;
    }
});
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR HELPING ME ♥

Comment: You have `return await new Promise(() => ...` without a passing in or calling `resolve()`. I very much doubt you need to be creating `Promise` objects at all

Comment: Also, you don't need `await` in front of `users.map()`

Comment: @Phil thank you so much for the quick response and the tip :)

Comment: @Phil but, if i remove the Promise i need to return something and i'm not able to return a setTimeout :/

Comment: @Phil if i turn this line "return await new Promise(() => setTimeout(async () => {"

into this

return setTimeout(async () => {

i get error message: Error serializing return value: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, your issue is with creating `Promise` objects and not passing in or calling `resolve()`. This means your final promises never resolve.

You also have an array of promises which should be within `Promise.all`.

I would create a simple, promise-based timeout function that should make things easier

```js
const timeoutPromise = (delay, fn)
  => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(fn()), delay))
```

then in the final part of your promise chain...

```js
if (currentCountRound >= caseCount) {
  await timeoutPromise(2000, async () => {
    await admin.database().ref('casebattle/' + pathId + '/winSumFinished').set(true);
    await admin.database().ref('/casebattle/' + pathId + '/isRunning').set(false);

    await Promise.all(users.map(async (user) => {
      await admin.database().ref('/playedbattles/' + user.userId + '/' + pathId + '/isRunning').set(false);
      await admin.database().ref('/playedbattles/' + user.userId + '/' + pathId + '/winSumFinished').set(true);
    }));
  });
} else {
  await admin.database().ref('casebattle/' + pathId + '/currentCountRound').transaction(currentCountRound => currentCountRound + 1);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much! its working ♥ Function execution took 2133 ms, finished with status: 'ok'